# I'm trying to reference the label value in my tab in Oracle Apex 5

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have several tabs in my APEX application.  The first is "Arlington".  I want to reference that in my query.  In other words I want to have a query that displays data where the city = whatever the tab might say.  In this example, it would obviously be Arlington.  Am I being clear?  I know there is a way to do it.  I know my tab name is T_ARLINGTON.  But I don't know how to reference the actual text of the tab.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create one page item and mention the tab title like ( &P1_NAME.), now refresh the page the text item value should be applied the tab title. this method showing the dynamic tab title...

Comment: Thank you Parthi!  I will implement this change.  What I ended up doing in the meantime was creating a hidden variable and set it equal to static value of "Arlington".  Then I was able to make the tab text (and the where statement in my queries) point to that hidden variable.  I'm trying to simplify my page so that all data can be based on one item (or page component).  Then I can simply change that one item and apply that change to the entire page.  Thank you again!